# Load scripts after page load - Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am creating a Firefox extension. I want load my external js file for all web pages on load time using Firefox extension. I can successfully load all js file on load event in my html file. But how can i execute into my extension.

```
window.onload = load;
function load() 
{               
      var filerefs=document.createElement('script')
      filerefs.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
      filerefs.setAttribute("src", 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')
      var head = doc.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ].appendChild( filerefs );
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Is `load()` not fired or is it fired but you getting an error / tag is not loading?

Comment: You mean you want to inject some JS into every webpage that is opened?

Comment: Should be noted that injecting (remote) javascript into random pages is strongly discouraged for security and compatibility reasons. If you're an SDK user, have a look at page-mod instead.

Comment: @Matthew Gertner  you are correct. i want this method. how can i set it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect page load and not application load, you should do it like this (this first part should be in your main overlay file):

```
// do not try to add a callback until the browser window has
// been initialised. We add a callback to the tabbed browser
// when the browser's window gets loaded.
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  // Add a callback to be run every time a document loads.
  // note that this includes frames/iframes within the document

  gBrowser.addEventListener("load", load(event), true);
}, false);
```

Reference from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load)

I added the event to the load function because the event fires not only on the load itself, but also on other elements, so you have to validate that you are doing it only once (reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/On_page_load) ):

```
function load(event) {
    if (event.originalTarget.nodeName == "#document") {
        var htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
        var doc = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument;

        var filerefs = doc.createElementNS(htmlns,'script');
        filerefs.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        filerefs.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
        doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(filerefs);
    }
}
```

Instead of using document.getElement..., we have to position on the content of the page, otherwise you are getting elements from your addon (using gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument gives you access to the current page's dom). And on the createlement, we want to create html elements, so you define and use the html namespace (reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS) ).

This should do the trick:

[image]

Comment: i want find all img tags for loading page. please help me

Comment: You just want to find the images in the page? You don't have another reason to load the script on pageload? If so, you might want to accept this question and start a new one asking for that, because that wasn't mentioned in your original question and this one might be useful for anyone with a valid use case.
As for finding the images, please explain better what you want to do with the images on that new question

Comment: i am accept this answer.  my another question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031833/call-jquery-function-after-page-load-not-working-firefox-extension please help me