# call jquery function after page load not working - Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I've been working on Create Firefox extension. i can inject some js file for all webpages. this function works fine.

```
codevar myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
        if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        if ((aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName == '#document') && 
       (aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView.location.href == gBrowser.currentURI.spec)) 
    {
        //alert('loaded');
         var htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
        var doc = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument;

          var filerefs = doc.createElementNS(htmlns,'script');
          filerefs.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
         filerefs.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
        doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(filerefs);

         var filerefst = doc.createElementNS(htmlns,'script');
        filerefst.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
         filerefst.setAttribute("src", url+"js/tipped/tipped.js");
         doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(filerefst);    
         filerefst.setAttribute(tripnow());
    }




    }
}
function  tripnow()
{
    //function working fine


    var j = $.noConflict();
            var imageslist = j('img');          
             var output = '';

                     // count image using jquery its not working 

             alert(imageslist.length);

             for (var i = 0, len = imageslist.length; i < len; i++) {        
             var images = j(imageslist).attr('src');
            //alert(images)
              Tipped.create(imageslist[i], "htmlphp.php?id="+i, 
              {
                  ajax: true,
                  skin: 'white',
                  hook: 'topleft',
                  afterUpdate: function() 
                  {
                     Cufon.replace('.HummingbirdDemo h1.museo');
                  }

             });
          }

}

window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);
```

I want to call my function after script loads. my function call working fine but my inner function script are in jquery its not working.

**Main Problem : I want count current page img tags using jquery**

Please advise

Comment: You wouldn't need to add jquery to the page to use it on the extension. That's not how it works. Are you using the firefox-addon-sdk?

Comment: @FilipeSilva yes Silva i am confusing. i need to show tool tip for all images. this is my add on i am try my local HTML file its working but unfortunately i am implement to my add on its not working

Comment: my html page link : http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/superfish/main/testingfinal.html

Comment: Don't ever inject remote javascript into arbitrary pages! 1. You just made it possible to MITM secure (https) pages - in Fx < 23 at least. 2. Your code might break a lot of pages that expect another version of jquery, or where your other code uses variable names already in use by the site. 3. addons.mozilla.org does not allow remote code injection, as such code may change at any time and hence cannot be code reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the page in addon-sdk, you have to use a content script. and you can use jquery on those, but not the way are using it. See [Content Scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html)